How to make permission of Bluetooth and Location on a mobile application by React Native?
I currently work on my academic project where I build mobile application using framework React Native. It need to get the device permission of Bluetooth and location for well performance.
I building application for Android devices, I run my code prototype on Expo Go.
Can I get the permission request in Expo Go for test is it work? If permission allowed while asking the device will actually ON the Bluetooth and location?
If not, what's the best way to proceed this?
I need solution on this for clarification from those who know.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
